# Call function each time while mapping each element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to call a function as react native maps each element. The function determines properties of the rendered component randomly , so that each component in renderComponent is different. Item is an argument that renderComponent takes up and so is i.

Side note : I've tried using state but you can't loop on state and change its values continuously.

```
cont randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
class whatever extends Component {
  change() {
   const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
 }

   renderComponent() {
    if(randomNumber === 0) {
     // Some cool code to set a random properties to the component 
    } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
    // Same thing here and so on and so forth 
    }
 }
  render() {
   return this.props.data.map(this.change.bind(this), (item, i)=> {
     return ({this.renderComponent(item)});
   }
 }
}
```

But when I try this I just get a blank, the component does not render cause I think item as an argument isn't passing

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings the issue is map isn't taking the second argument of (item, i) I think and due to this I get nothing.

Comment: Why are you providing `this.change.bind(this)` as first argument for `map`. What do you expect?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings that's mentioned in the text , I want it to rerun every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to to is to call a function with the item that's being mapped in each iteration. restructure your function to be more like

```
return this.props.data.map((item, i) => {
   this.renderComponent(item)
})
```

Your change function should return a value that can be accessed from the renderComponent

the randomnumber constant cannot be accessed outside the scope that it's defined in. declare your random number as a variable outside that you can mutate or as a key in the state object that you can access from the renderComponent function would do much good. Basically, your three functions should be

```
change(){this.setState({randomNum: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) })}

renderComponent(){this.state.randomNum === 0 ? "do something" : "do something else"}

return this.props.data.map((item, i) => {
this.change() //calling this function to keep changing the number held at the state
   this.renderComponent(item)
})
```

Don't forget to initialize a state key of randomNum too

Comment: Keeping this.change() inside the map function just executes it a single time , I've tried it

Comment: Just implemented it now.... works fine here, remove the binding of this.change.bind() you called on your map function, also, make sure the data prop you're passing is also populated

Answer (score 0):

In the following lines of code, you aren't returning anything on the array `map`:

```
return this.props.data.map(this.change.bind(this), (item, i) => {
     {this.renderComponent(item)}
}
```

You should return somehting in order of it to work. Do this instead:

```
return this.props.data.map(this.change.bind(this), (item, i) => {
     return this.renderComponent(item)
}
```

If you are not using React 16 you would have to place everything inside a JSX block.

Comment: Sorry that isn't the issue , that's my fault. I think the issue is that map isn't taking the second argument and not passing item and i

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `this.change()` inside `renderComponent()`.

Keeping a variable outside class is not best practice. If you need, you could assign it to `this.randomVariable`

```js
class Whatever extends React.Component {
    change() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); //Increased number limit to show it is being called each time
    }

    renderComponent(item) {
      const randomNum = this.change();
      if(randomNum===1) {
        //something and so on
      }
      return randomNum; //Just to show it is different each time
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {
            this.props.data.map((item,i)=>{
              return <p>{this.renderComponent(item)}</p>
            })
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Whatever data={[1, 2, 3, 4]} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can avoid the wrapping `div` if you are using React 16.